# Varchar(max) cutting limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity, string-concatenation

I need a script to reseed every identity column on my database

I've done this:

```
DECLARE @sqlreseed nvarchar(max)

SELECT 
    @sqlreseed = COALESCE(@sqlreseed + ' ', '') + 'set @id = (select isnull(max(' + cast(c.name as nvarchar(max)) +'), 0) + 1  from ' + CAST(t.name as nvarchar(max)) + ') DBCC CHECKIDENT (''' + cast(t.name as nvarchar(max)) +''', RESEED, @id); '
FROM 
    sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables AS t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN 
    sys.identity_columns AS c on c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]

SET @sqlreseed = cast(cast('declare @id int ' as nvarchar(max)) + @sqlreseed as nvarchar(max))

EXEC(@sqlreseed)
```

but I get a syntax error over a column.

The script generated seems to be fine

```
declare @id int set @id = (select isnull(max(SpecPositionID), 0) + 1  from SpecPosition_TS) DBCC CHECKIDENT ('SpecPosition_TS', RESEED, @id);  set @id = (select isnull(max(AuditId), 0) + 1  from TS_User_Audit) DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TS_User_Audit', RESEED, @id);
```

and so on for each table. Each checkident works fine, but if I run it with the first query I've posted I get

> Incorrect syntax near 'BoxId'.

If I execute a `len(@sqlreseed)` I get 70905.

I have a lot of tables, but apparently the script is being cut. I read somewhere that the problem if is that I concatenate strings I have to cast all of them to `nvarchar(max)` because if not it would be cut to 8000 but that's all I've read.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Dump the script as text and search for BoxId?

Comment: I did it but the script as text cuts it even before than 70905 length. Or I may be doing it wrong :P

Comment: Try wrapping all names in `[ ]` in your generated SQL. Maybe you have a column with special characters in it.

Comment: Do a search for BoxId in the NVARCHAR with PATINDEX and return a SUBSTRING (do from -100 to +100 from the index returned and widen if needed). See what is wrong with what is returned.

Comment: You should be very wary of this technique for building strings, since [Microsoft warn that it's not reliable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189484.aspx): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row"

Comment: good point. Anyway the article that explains that states that unexpected output may come when using order by, which is not my case. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Blorgbeard posted in the comments, the solution was to use `[]` in the columns names for the generated string.

Probably there was a column name with some special name or characters.

I also used cast to `nvarchar(max)` in all concatenations to make sure the limit wasn't limited to 8000, as I've read

The V 2.0 (fully working) is this one.

```
declare @sqlreseed nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sqlreseed = COALESCE(cast(@sqlreseed as nvarchar(max)) + ' ', '') + 'set @id = (select isnull(max([' + cast(c.name as nvarchar(max)) +']), 0) + 1  from [' + CAST(s.name as nvarchar(max)) + '].[' + CAST(t.name as nvarchar(max)) + ']) DBCC CHECKIDENT (''' + cast(t.name as nvarchar(max)) +''', RESEED, @id); '
FROM sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.identity_columns AS c on c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
SET @sqlreseed = cast(cast('declare @id int ' as nvarchar(max)) + @sqlreseed as nvarchar(max))
exec(@sqlreseed)
```

Comment: Yes I tried, that's why I upvoted your answer. I cannot set my answer as accepted until tomorrow :P which is the query that actually solved the question (using []). Anyway I'll keep your query for an improvement now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT SqlCommand + CHAR(10)--this concatenation without a column name is the magic to get "xml free" xml :-) Try this without the "+CHAR(10)"
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS inx, 'declare @id int;' AS SqlCommand
    UNION 
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) --Dummy Order
        ,'set @id = (select isnull(max(' + cast(c.name as nvarchar(max)) +'), 0) + 1  from ' + CAST(t.name as nvarchar(max)) + '); DBCC CHECKIDENT (''' + cast(t.name as nvarchar(max)) +''', RESEED, @id); '
    FROM 
        sys.schemas AS s
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables AS t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.identity_columns AS c on c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
) AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.inx 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Within the XML Viewer you are (almost) unlimited. Right click into your query and chose options, tick the grid and set the XML (last point) to "unlimited".

Btw: The string concatenation with `SELECT @var=@var+...` is quite slow. The way shown above should perform much better...